# jsTree disable some of the checkboxes

Tags: jstree

Using jsTree (3.1.0+) with checkbox plugin is it possible to allow not all checkboxes to check - disable some of them?

I found solution for old versions of jsTree here [jstree disable checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487305/jstree-disable-checkbox) but it didn't work on jsTree 3.1.0+ versions.

Solution of hiding checkbox [jsTree Hide Checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112567/jstree-hide-checkbox) is working, but if I click on the folder, hidden checkbox will be checked anyway.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Keep in mind unless you are using `checkbox.tie_selection` as `false`, selecting and checking are the same thing.

So you can simply call `.disable_node()` on the nodes you want disabled.

---

**EDIT**: Use the latest code from the repo (note - not 3.1.1, but the latest code):
https://github.com/vakata/jstree/archive/master.zip

You can now specify the `checkbox_disabled` state:

```
<div id="jstree">
    <ul>
        <li data-jstree='{"checked":true}'>checked</li>
        <li data-jstree='{"checkbox_disabled":true}'>checked</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In JSON too of course:

```
{ "id" : "Test node", "state" : { "checkbox_disabled" : true } }
```

You can also change the disabled state of a checkbox at runtime using `enable_checkbox(node)` and `disable_checkbox(node)`.

Comment: I am using `tie_selection:false`, but if I will use `.disable_node()` then it will not set node to "unclickable" at all? Will `select_node` events trigger?

Comment: In that case the above solution will not work, I will see if I can think of a way to disable the checkbox only.

Comment: It would be great! I will be looking forward for your solution.

Comment: I will add a state property for disabling the checkbox, it will be live in a day or two.

Comment: @Orbitum I just updated my answer to reflect the latest changes to the jsTree API - you can get the code from the repo.

Comment: Awesome! I will try it ASAP! Thank you for such an operative answer and godlike support :)

Comment: When a checkbox is disabled it seems that you can still check/uncheck it by clicking anywhere else on the node...

Answer (score 5):

To completely hide checkbox from the specific node, add following JS code

```js
$('#tree_2').on('ready.jstree', function () {
  $("#tree_2").jstree().get_node("node1_id").a_attr["class"] = "no_checkbox";
  $("#tree_2").jstree().get_node("node2_id").a_attr["class"] = "no_checkbox";

....
});
```

and in CSS, add the following style

```css
.no_checkbox > i.jstree-checkbox {
 display: none;
}
```

It will completely hide checkbox from provided node id, this worked like a charm for me. [Thanks to this link](http://jsfiddle.net/2kwkh2uL/4426/).